# Project/solution class inheritance tree and dependency graph

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, dependencies

Is there any way to get inheritance tree and/or class dependency graph for the whole Visual Studio project/solution **from code**? I know that it's possible to iterate through all classes and check keywords but I'm looking for easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Dependency graph](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2010/05/11/visual-studio-2010-how-to-understand-your-code-using-dependency-graphs-sequence-diagrams-and-the-architecture-explorer.aspx) feature in Visual Studio 2010. It is a new architecture tool available in VS2010.

The generated graph looks something like this,

[image: Dependency graph]

**Similar question**

- [Dependency graph of Visual Studio projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598129/dependency-graph-of-visual-studio-projects)

Comment: That's not a programmatically way, but I think I will able to use it via VS SDK. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on your project and select View Class Diagram. Is that what looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate can do this, using the Architecture functionality. In Professional/Express you can generate a class-diagram, but that's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also used the tool NDepend to get a [custom inheritance graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx#Inherit) over a VS project, a VS solution or even multiple VS solutions. The graph would look like that:

[image: NDepend custom inheritance graph]

Answer (score 0):

[Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Architecture__Project_Dependencies_Exploration.html#understanding-links-between-projects) generates something like this
[image]