# Is there a tool for Visual studio 2010 solution dependencies?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dependencies

I need to bundle up all projects in a solution for a code review, and there's a lot more code in the file directory structure than is required for this particular solution.

I found this for VS 2008 http://vsdm.codeplex.com/ but I haven't found anything for VS 2010. Does something exist?

It would be really nice to find a tool that can export the solution and all projects, source, and resources, to a zip or some other folder.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this one http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/visual-studio-solution-dependency-visualizer/

It doesn't help with packaging up the source for the solution, but may be helpful in determining what needs to be packaged up. I also found this answer on the SO site: [Dependency graph of Visual Studio projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598129/dependency-graph-of-visual-studio-projects) and have VS Ultimate so perhaps that will get me closer.