# Generating a class reference graph

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class

I would like to generate a class reference graph of my project on Visual Studio.

Some Google research deal with other programs except Visual Studio

Comment: You can use [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/)

Comment: What do you mean by reference? Class hierarchy? Or...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dependency graph of Visual Studio projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598129/dependency-graph-of-visual-studio-projects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this right, Visual Studio has this feature already.
Reference this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3zaa390(v=vs.90).aspx