# Drawing dependency graphs between methods in .NET

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to familiarize myself with a significant amount of existing code. Until recently I used to draw dependency graphs ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_graph), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd409453.aspx)) between methods, by hand, to help me visualise the code. But this is very tedious.

Today this can also be automated using [Visual Studio Ultimate's "Code Map"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/26/introducing-code-map-in-visual-studio-2012-update-1-ctp.aspx), [NDepend](http://ndepend.com/Features.aspx#Diagrams), and apparently also [Debugger Canvas](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4a979842-b9aa-4adf-bfef-83bd428a0acb).

(And there are [a lot of solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598129/dependency-graph-of-visual-studio-projects) to graphing project dependencies, but that is not what I want)

Can anyone suggest a way to speed up or automate the creation of such dependency graphs, without an expensive tool? Or am I stuck drawing them by hand?
(I am counting Debugger Canvas as an expensive tool since it still requires Visual Studio Ultimate).

Comment: Noting the post <http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186245/a-borderline-between-on-topic-questions-and-questions-about-library-recommendati> I will try to rephrase my question. I realise that the answer does not need to be a tool/extension, but at the same time I believe it is a question that may benefit many developers. I have also drawn attention to some existing solutions to the problem that do not meet my needs, i.e. I have "[described] the problem and what has been done so far to solve it".

Comment: When down-voting please motivate what is wrong with my question. i.e. (1) does it lack research effort (2) is it unclear (3) is it not useful (since those are the criteria for a downvote)

Comment: What is the line between "Expensive tool" and "Non-expensive tool", is it just the line of being free vs non-free? Or would you be willing to spend something like $10, $15, $30, ...?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain technically I mean zero marginal cost for me. Which probably implies free (Although a "free" solution that requires VS Professional is not really free, but does have zero marginal cost for me).
I ask for a free solution, because my employer will not be willing to pay for such a tool, even though I would like to use it. I suppose I would consider an option costing $10-15, but not much more since I do not earn in USD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) will [create them](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html) for you, though you'll need to install [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/) to get the graphics.

It will also take your xml doc comments and turn them into html (or other) documentation pages, and you can tell it to create caller and call graphs as well as the usual inheritance diagrams.

Doxygen is great (and free).

If you don't want the automated help, then I can only suggest a pad and a pencil.

Comment: Doxygen seems to support C# but it says nothing about .NET. It seems like this is the best solution available at present though.