# Visual Studio Team Foundation Server - Need to find out if a project is referenced anywhere else in source control (Cleaning Up)

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, tfs-power-tools

Am performing a re-structuring and cleanup of a large, heavily branched source control system (Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013). I need a quick way to find out if projects we are cleaning up (deleting, archiving, moving around) are referenced anywhere else in the source control so that they can all be moved efficiently.

Note, we are only interested in project level references (references to .CSPROJ files) and not individual resource/code/etc files.

Kind of solutions I am looking for --
 1. Ready-made TFS Power Tool
 2. TFS scripts
 3. Built-in TFS command (something like this if it exists...  "> TFS /find-dependency "foo.csproj") <--- nirvana

EDIT: Following a suggestion given below, I got this link: [Dependency graph of Visual Studio projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598129/dependency-graph-of-visual-studio-projects) and it has the best suggestion I have found so far for automation. Extending this PowerShell script may be the best way forward.

EDIT: Incidentally, my team of people approach is completed and now I have an Excel sheet full of dependencies that can be used and/or scripted against. This will work for me for now.

QUESTION CLOSED.

Comment: Please give some specifics about what you have already tried.

Comment: Well, right now, I have a team of people loading up each SLN and filling out an Excel sheet :( Someone is also trying a grep script in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio Ultimate, you can create dependency graphs. Although, they don't only show dependencies for Project reference only but the visualization is a great help.

Have a look at http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2013/06/12/visual-studio-ultimate-2012s-generate-dependency-graph-helps-quickly-visualize-system-dependencies/

The following post might be helpful as well

[Dependency graph of Visual Studio projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598129/dependency-graph-of-visual-studio-projects)

Comment: No, that wont work. I need something that shows me if a .csproj file is used in any other project in my TFS. I need something that does not require me to open up each SLN and do this graphing. (I am still giving you credit for the answer though). Thanks!