# Determining projects that depend on the given one

Tags: visual-studio

I'm given a solution with >100 projects. ~15 projects are executables, others are libraries.

I'm looking at a particular library. How do I look up which other libraries/executables reference (or depend on) the library?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the broader problem is address and solved: project dependency graph.

This SO question lists solutions: [Dependency graph of Visual Studio projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598129/dependency-graph-of-visual-studio-projects)