# Dependency graph of visual studio C++ projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How can I get a graph of the dependencies between C++ (vcxproj) files in a large visual studio 2013 solution. I've got the Ultimate version and there are architecture diagram generation tools, but they always seem to fail.

I found the following for C# which has some good answers.
[Dependency graph of Visual Studio projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598129/dependency-graph-of-visual-studio-projects)